# Marking Input As Optional in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

When [defining a custom op in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), is there any way to / concept of an optional input? For example I am working on a fused convolution Op that takes input, weights, and ideally optionally a bias term. Ideally the caller of the Op can use it without supplying any bias term.

Answer (score 5):

The [mini-language](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/baa85cbf5e51a21f58bc28ef9eedc122e6118eb8/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h#L178) for TensorFlow op definition does not have native support for optional Tensor-valued inputs. There are a few alternatives that are commonly used:

1. Use an `Attr()` instead of an `Input()` when defining your op. Since the structure of the graph is fixed at graph construction time, so will be the presence or absence of an optional input, so you may be able to encode the information as a compile-time value.
2. Make the input mandatory at the op-definition level, and add a Python wrapper function that makes the corresponding argument optional, and adds a default/sentinel value if it is not specified. For example the `axis` argument to [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/baa85cbf5e51a21f58bc28ef9eedc122e6118eb8/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1184) is an optional tensor-valued argument that will be filled in if the caller does not provide one.
3. Op registration supports lists of tensors, so you could use a list of length 0 or 1 to represent an optional input.